# How to troubleshoot a potentiometer problem

Tags: amplifier, audio, raspberry-pi, potentiometer, adafruit

I went over my league and started the [Adafruit's PiGrrl Zero project](https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-zero), and then when succeeded, wanted to implement the [audio amplifier add-on suggestions](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1621907).

Anyways, this morning, the audio amp's potentiometer worked perfectly fine, and then not.

I opened the case and looked at voltages at the pins and here is what I measured:

- black on left, red on middle: 2.67V
- black on left, red on right: 2.67V

Then, looking at the wheel:

[image: black on left, red on wheel cursor: 1.6V]

- black on left, red on wheel's **cursor** (metal part in the black disc, 120° from right): 1.6V

[image]

- black on left, red on wheel's **cursor** (metal part in the black disc, 45-50° from right): 0.8V

I don't want to remove the potentiometer from the rest unless strictly necessary, but I have the feeling that everything is working fine except the connection between the wheel and the 3 pins (or at least one of the non-gnd pins), since the wheel is adjusting correctly the resistance, but nothing changes pin-wise.

What can I do to troubleshoot while limiting the ungluing/unsoldering operations?

Thanks.

**Temp edits based on discussion**:

0. The goal of the troubleshooting is obviously to make this potentiometer do its job (adjusting volume). Currently, only low sound is possible, and the knob is not doing anything.
1. I'm following this protocol: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1621907/files
2. In case of dead links, here is a printscreen of the audio amp connection:
   [image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly your problem is?

Comment: "since the wheel is adjusting correctly the resistance" if you are sure of that, then the fault is probably somewhere else and you will have to check the rest of the circuit.

Comment: @PatrickFiedler: the fact that both pins are at 2.7V is not evidence that the problems lies in the potentiometer itself?

Comment: @earl : my problem is that the potentiometer is not doing the job. Sound's volume is steady and low. Note: putting the multimeter in Ohmmeter (so with a small current, right?) is actually creating sound amplification if I do "black to center pin, red to right pin".

Comment: oh,when you mentioned measuring on the wheel's cursor I didnt 100% get it. So to be clear: the value changes, when measuring between GND and the center metal bit of the potentiometer,but NOT when measuring at the pin?
In that case I would agree, either the potentiometer is defective or something else is pulling up that connection.I'd make sure to check for shorts and if all connections are soldered properly,maybe you have a loose contact somewhere.

Also @ your other comment: NEVER measure resistance in a live circuit! You wont get an accurate reading and might even destroy your multimeter.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I can even damage the speaker, but the sound of the speaker is giving me immediate feedback on what is happening. but you're right, I should start getting good habits asap. As for "shorts and soldering": what would be your advice to test them in the least invasive way? To be more precise, it is not the "center metal pin", but the bit with an angle. The central part allows to rotate: if I could remove it, it would be easier but I don't have the tools. Hence my question.

Comment: Sadly I dont think there is much more you can do without opening up the whole thing and checking out the individual components. you need access at the different parts' pins to find out more but to do that you probably have to disassemble the whole device... I think right now best would be to wait if someone else has an idea, but dont get your hopes up - if the circuit is not working now there is something defective/wrong and you will have to get the proper tools to fix it anyways.

Comment: Thanks. And please pardon my naive hope in getting magical solutions. I know how it feels when roles are reversed and yet keep behaving like a miracle could happen :D

Comment: The volume control on an audio amplifier is usually very simple with no DC voltage on any of the pins of the volume control. Please post the schematic of the amplifier with volume control.

Comment: @Audioguru: not sure I understand your comment, but please have a look at the editted version of the question. I added the schematics.

Comment: The photo showing the pot connections seems to be incorrect.  Normally, the input signal will go to one end of the pot, with the other end to Ground.  The wiper (moving contact, usually the center terminal) of the pot should go to the speaker.  The left and center wires on the pot should be exchanged.

Comment: Check carefully the specs of the pot.  Pot wipers are typically designed for very little current.  Driving a speaker through the pot wiper is probably asking for trouble.

Comment: I agree that a speaker is NEVER connected in series with a pot like that. Then they both have DC in them.

Comment: Indeed, I guess you guys are right: I removed te pot and replaced it with a new one (from the same aliexpress batch) and it started working again. Then I turned off the gameboy, waited, and started it again to play with my daughter and I could smell a bad smell, even though no smoke was getting out. After a few games, the same behavior as previously started happening again. The speaker is still functional though.

Comment: @Audioguru what would be the correct wiring? I guess that Peter Bennett's reply still keeps things in serie, doesn't it?